# Store ints from text file with mmap

Tags: c, mmap

so I got this text file which has a kind of matrix

```
4x4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

and I want to store the digits using the mmap() function.

So far I have this:

```
char *file_in_mem = mmap(NULL, row*col*sizeof(int), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fileno(f1), 0);
if (file_in_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
   printf("map failed\n");
   return 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++) {
   printf("[%d] : [%d]\n",i,atoi(&file_in_mem[i]);
}
```

but it doesn't return the correct numbers and if I try to change something it just slaps me with a segmentation fault... any help?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Remove the `&` in `atoi(&file_in_mem[i]`. In addition, your file contains spaces, `atoi` won't handle these nicely too. And your `row` and `col` are likely not accounting them. And there is no way it is going to work with more than one digit numbers.

Comment: the problem is if I remove the atoi is stores the ASCII value and I don't want that...

Comment: You have a text file but much of your code makes it looks like you are treating it as a *binary* file instead.  For example, your `length` argument to mmap is `row*col*sizeof(int)`, but the actual size of your text file is likely going to be  different than that.  Just run `ls -l yourfile.txt` to see the actual length of the file in bytes.

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira This whole code is not doing what you want. You could use `sscanf` to do the conversions.

Comment: You probably get a segmentation fault when you call `atoi(&file_in_mem[i])` and `i` is larger than or equal to the length of your file.  Also, I'm not sure if `mmap` puts a null termination character at the end of the file.  If it doesn't then `atoi` might read off the end of the your file and read invalid regions of memory.

Comment: Use `fstat` (or similar) to get the file of the file into a `struct stat` and use that as the size argument for `mmap`.

Comment: Yeah, and then you'll have to write a more sophisticated parser... numbers in a text file take up a variable amount of space, and there is also whitespace in the file, so you can't just go to `file_in_mem[x * y]` and expect to get the number at column x and row y.

Comment: I don't think it's a good question: here is a snippet that doesn't work, if I make an unspecified change it segfault.  Please update question with a [mre], hard-code the input as part of the program, eliminate what is irrelevant (for instance if mmap works, just give us a `char s[] = 4x4\n...";`), and explain what the problem is (usually, it's output but in this case it appear to be that file_in_mem doesn't contain what you expect, or maybe it's that you post-processing step doesn't work).